# list index error out of range #define coordinates problem in yolov3

Tags: yolo

I am quite new to yolov3 and have been given a task to get the program to annotate fish on pictures. However, I am helplessly stuck at 2 things which may be related to each other:
1.
txt_file_paths = glob.glob(r"data/obj/*.txt")
for i, file_path in enumerate(txt_file_paths):
# get image size
with open(file_path, "r") as f_o:
lines = f_o.readlines()

```
    text_converted = []
    for line in lines:
        print(line)
        numbers = re.findall("[0-9.]+", line)
        print(numbers)
        if numbers:

            # Define coordinates
            text = "{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}".format(0, numbers[1], numbers[2], numbers[3], numbers[4])
            text_converted.append(text)
            print(i, file_path)
            print(text)
```

...
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

in <cell line: 8>()
19
20                 # Define coordinates
---> 21                 text = "{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}".format(0, numbers[1], numbers[2], numbers[3], numbers[4])
22                 text_converted.append(text)
23                 print(i, file_path)

IndexError: list index out of range

2.
Wrong annotation: x = 0, y = 0, < 0 or > 1, file: data/obj/01_20230623045959_5001.txt

Wrong annotation: x = 0, y = 0, < 0 or > 1, file: data/obj/06_20230623045959_7801.txt

This continues to the very last of my 600 images.

I have looked at this and other forums and tried enough things to solve the issue that I can't even remember what I already tried. If anyone knows what I am doing wrong, please tell me